# Power BI Filter Selection

Tags: selection

In Qlik Sense, after select a slice item, press ENTER, it filters out other items, and only keep the selected one. Power BI shows selected item as highlighted, and other items greyed out. The behavior is quite different. 2 Questions

1. Can Power BI behave similar to Qlik?
2. After an item is selected, and if I navigate to another page, the selection disappears. Do I miss some option in Power BI?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Power BI visualization is bit differ from Qlik.

```
1   Can Power BI behave similar to Qlik?
```

Power bi standard behavior is to gray out. But you can replicate this by using measure upto some extend.

```
2   After an item is selected, and if I navigate to another page, the selection disappears. Do I miss some option in Power BI?
```

Yes you can do that use [slicer synchronization](https://radacad.com/sync-slicers-in-power-bi)